# Using a tool or technique: usar? utilizar? empregar?

Tags: diferenças, uso-de-palavras, sinônimos

I've been told before, by a Portuguese speaker, not to use the verb *usar*  to describe using a tool. They told me to use *utilizar* instead. I've also seen *empregar* used in similar situations.

Which of those verbs are appropriate for referring to *using a tool, technique, or word or phrase?* Which are more commonly used for this? Do they have different connotations when used in this way? Is there a better alternative that I've missed?

When I check a dictionary, it looks to me like all three could work. I can't tell the difference from the definitions I found (unrelated definitions not included below):

> ### [usar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/usar)
>
> - Pôr em uso, pôr em prática. (Usa-se também com a preposição *de*.)
> - Empregar, servir-se de.
>
> ### [utilizar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/utilizar)
>
> - Servir-se de.
> - Empregar utilmente.
> - Sacar partido de; aproveitar.
>
> ### [empregar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/empregar)
>
> - Fazer uso de; servir-se de; gastar, despender; preencher.

(Please feel free to respond in either Portuguese or English. I didn't feel that I could express this question correctly in Portuguese, by its nature.)

Comment: As *Corpus Queries* feitas em http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/ produzem resultados relativos a: (a) utilizar uma ferramenta; (b) usar (ou empregar) uma técnica; (c) usar (ou utilizar) um método; (d) usar (ou utilizar ou empregar) uma palavra; (e) usar (ou utilizar ou empregar) uma frase; e NÃO registam resultados quanto a (f) usar (ou empregar) uma ferramenta; (g) empregar um método.

Comment: Mas eu usei esse Corpus, e ferramentas eles podem não usar, mas tesouras já usam: 8 casos. Por outro lado só as utilizam 3 vezes, e em pelo menos duas não são tesouras normais. Falam em cortar chapa, tesouras elétricas, e isso.

Comment: A explicação tradicional da diferença que se apresenta no castelhano e no inglês (que tem essas três palavras) é que se usa *usar* quando usas algo numa forma «normal» e *utilizar* quando fazes uso dalgo numa forma menos tradicional (usar martelo com pregos, mas utilizar o martelo para, não sei, apoiar uma mesa).  Segundo as definições na pergunta, parece-me que a diferença é quase a mesma e que (como naquelas línguas) *usar* é más quotidiano, havendo-se adicionado o significado tradicional de utilizar. Empregar sói connotar usos para um fim, é dizer, empregar um martelo para martelar pregos).

Answer (score 8):

As André pointed out, *usar* and *utilizar* are synonyms in the context you described, so I can only speculate why your friend told you to use *utilizar* instead of *usar*.

I believe your friend was not correcting your grammar, he just meant to give you a style advice. Portuguese formal writing style tend to favor the use of larger, more sophisticated words instead of short, more common ones. That's sort of contrary to English writing style guides I know, which tend to favor smaller words for a more concise writing.

In any case, using *usar* is perfectly acceptable in this context. Choosing *utilizar* over *usar* seems to me like a matter of style.

Comment: Deve ser por um motivo semelhante a este que em Portugal dizemos utilizador (de utilizar) de um computador, por exemplo, e no Brasil, usuário (de usar).

Comment: Utilizar um utensílio, por fazer uso útil. Tomar cuidado com usar pessoas, pois às vezes tem sentido negativo de abusar física ou psicologicamente delas, enquanto utilizar é mais neutro. "eu usei/utilizei aquelas pessoas para construir a casa".

Answer (score 6):

In brazilian portuguese, in the context you mention (usage of an object of any kind), and when used alone, these verbs are exact synonyms. *Utilizar* and *empregar* are slightly more formal, and that's all.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT (Sept 27th, 2015) My answer refers to these three words as they are used in Brazil, in the spoken language.

**Nada como dar exemplos:**

- Eu uso um alicate ou um martelo. Se eu utilizar um alicate, serei chamado de pedante.  Se eu empregar um martelo, serei motivo de risos.
- Eu emprego ou uso vários termos estrangeiros quando falo, mas não os utilizo.
- O que a senhora utilizou ou usou para tirar a mancha?
- Eu uso o meu computador diariamente. Eu o utilizo para fazer impressos e convites.

A escolha entre USAR/UTILIZAR/EMPREGAR é dependente daquilo que se vai USAR/UTILIZAR/EMPREGAR.

Comment: Você está falando sobre Portugal ou em geral?

Comment: Sobre Brasil. Em Portugal não utilizamos "eu o utilizo" nem "o que a senhora"; utilizamos "eu utilizo-o" e "o que é que a senhora".

Comment: Isso deve ser influência das tuas visitas a Portugal, pois eu também empregaria essas palavras da mesma maneira.

Comment: Minha opinião pessoal é que "utilizo-o", embora não seja um cacófato, soa mal.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu estava a referir-me apenas à escolha entre _usar, utilizar_ e _empregar_: eu empregaria nos teu exemplos as mesmas palavras que tu.

Comment: "Eu tenho um martelo e utilizo-o quando tenho de pregar um parafuso."; "Eu tenho de empregar o João ele tem muito talento."; "Eu costumo usar estas cuecas do batman." (Não consegui arranjar exemplo com empregar na minha cabeça com o sentido de usar)

Comment: @JorgeB.   "Neste caso em particular o emprego da preposição é obrigatório"  "Há que se empregar a preposição".

Comment: @Centaurus eu consigo ver o significado e a lógica do emprego da palavra emprego, mas não me soa nada bem empregrar aqui esse termo. ;)

Comment: @JorgeB.  Aqui no Brasil, é de uso corrente nas salas de aula.